# C# Hangman, check if whole word matches

Tags: c#

beginner in C# here. I have written a console game of the old classic game Hangman, were the user guesses wich letters are in a word without seeing them.

My code works well, i just want to add one more thing, and i dont now how to go about it. As of current, if you press "3" and play the game you can only guess one one character at a time. I want to make the user able to guess the WHOLE word, and if its correct, match it against the word and write it out.

As of current i have a exception that writes out a ERROR message if the user tries to write in more then one character.

I have been stuck on this really long, and would love if anyone could tell me how to implement this in my code, my code is as follows.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;//*Notering, ta reda på mer om linq
    using System.Media; 
    public class WordList : List<string> //Skapar klass WordList 
    {
    }
    public class Hangman
    {
    /* 
     * TO-DO-LIST:
     * Användaren ska kunna skriva in ett helt ord och  detta ska sedan
     * jämföras med de ord som finns i programmets lista. Se 10.7 i boken.
     */

    private static WordList words;
    private static Random randomR = new Random();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { /*Konsol utseende */
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen; //Ändra konstoltext färg till röd
    Console.Title = "C# Hangman"; //Ger konsolspelet en titel
    Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till C# Hangman-spelet!");                 //Hälsningsfras när spelet öppnas
    initializeWordList();

    //_______________________START-          MENY_______________________________________________
    int MenuChoice = 0; //Skapar heltals variabel som kommer användas i         switch sats
    while (MenuChoice != 4) //Loop som visar menyn tills spelaren gör ett val
    {

        Console.Write("\n\t1) Lägg till ord");
        Console.Write("\n\t2) Visa ordlista");
        Console.Write("\n\t3) Spela");
        Console.Write("\n\t4) Avsluta\n\n");

        Console.Write("\n\tVälj 1-4: ");        //Välj menyval

        MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //Spelarens val registreras i 
                                                          //tidigare skapad variabel
        switch (MenuChoice)  //Switch sats startar.                           
        {  /*Alternativ 1 - Lägg till ord*/
            case 1: 
                Console.Clear();//Rensar konsolfönster
                Console.Write("\n\tLägg till ett ord\n\n");
                var insert = Console.ReadLine(); //Läser av inskrivet ord
                words.Add(insert); //Lägger till ord i lista
                Console.Write("\n\tOrdlista\n\n");
                words.Sort();
                foreach (string w in words) 
                    Console.WriteLine(w); //Skriv ut för att verifiera att ordet lagts till
                break;

            /*Alternativ 2 - Visa ordlista*/
            case 2: 
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("\n\tOrdlista\n\n");
                foreach (string w in words) // Skriver ut ordlista
                    Console.WriteLine(w);
                break;

            /*Alternativ 3 - Spela*/
            case 3:
                /*Spelar bakgrundsmusik i loop medans Alternativ 3 är valt*/
                (new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Program\Media\background.wav")).PlayLooping();
                Console.Clear();
                int numGuessesInt = -1; //Skapar variabel som används för att bestämma
                while (numGuessesInt == -1)//antal gissningar.

                {
                    /* Bestämmer antalet gissningar spelaren har.*/
                    userpickGuesses(ref numGuessesInt);
                }

                /* Väljer ut slumpartat ord*/
                string word = randomWord();


                /* skapar lista av char som visas */
                List<char> guessedLetters = new List<char>();
                bool solved = false;
                while (solved == false)
                {
                    /* Visning av sträng till spelare baserat på spelarens gissningar.
                     * Om spelaren ej lyckats gissa något rätt visas "_ _ _ " */
                    string wordToDisplay = showWord(guessedLetters, word);
                    /* Om strängen som returneras innehåller "_" karaktären, så har
                    * ej korrekt antal bokstäver gissats, för att kontrollera om spelare
                    * förlorar kollas det om variabel numGuessesLeft är mindre än 1.*/
                    if (!wordToDisplay.Contains("_"))
                    {
                        solved = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Grattis, du vann!  Ordet du gissa var:  " + word);
                        /* Kolla om spelare vill spela igen. Om dom vill det så
                        * sätts variabel solved till true, detta avslutar loopen.
                        * Om spelare ej vill spela igen kommer metoden userReplay stänga ner programmet*/
                        userReplay();
                    }
                    else if (numGuessesInt <= 0)
                    {
                        solved = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Trist kompis, du förlora! Det korrekta ordet var:  " + word);
                        userReplay();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Om spelaren varken vinner eller förlorar så
                        * visas ordet och antal gissningar minus 1.*/
                        letterGuess(guessedLetters, word, wordToDisplay, ref numGuessesInt);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 4: /*Alternativ 4 - Avsluta spelet*/
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tTryck på valfri tangent för att avsluta?\n\n");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error[1]: Fel tangent, testa igen");
                break;
        }

    }

}

    //_________________________Lista med färdigbestämda ord____________________________________________
    private static void initializeWordList()
    {
    words = new WordList();
    words.Add("projektarbete");         // innehåller ord: projektarbete
    words.Add("programmering");          // innehåller orden: projektarbete, programmering
    words.Add("csharp");
    words.Add("stenberg");
    words.Insert(1, "hårdvara"); // Innehåller orden: "projektarbete", "programmering", "csharp", 
    words.Sort();                // "stenberg" och "hårdvara"
}


    //___________________METOD-Välj antal gissningar_________________________________________________________

    private static void userpickGuesses(ref int userNumGuessesInt)
    {
    string numGuessesString = ""; //Intierar sträng med tomt innehåll
    Console.WriteLine("Välj antal gissningar: "); //Promptar spelare att ange antal gissningar
    numGuessesString = Console.ReadLine(); //Läser in antal gissningar av spelare
    try
    {
        userNumGuessesInt = Convert.ToInt32(numGuessesString); //Sträng görs om till heltal(int).
        if (!(userNumGuessesInt <= 20 & userNumGuessesInt >= 1))// Undantag om spelare skriver in för*
        {                                              //stort eller litet antal gissningar.
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        userNumGuessesInt = -1;
        Console.WriteLine("Error[2]: Fel antal gissningar");//Om undantaget är sant visas
    }                                                         //varnings meddelande
}

    //__________________METOD-Slumpat ord_________________________________________________

    private static string randomWord()
{
    return words[randomR.Next(0, words.Count() - 1)]; //*Notering, ta reda på mer om skillnad mellan .Count och .Count()
}


    //________________________METOD-Visa ord___________________________________________

    private static string showWord(List<char> guessedCharacters, string word)
    {
    string returnedWord = ""; //Initierar sträng med tomt innehåll
    if (guessedCharacters.Count == 0) 
    {
        foreach (char letter in word) //Visar karaktären "_" för varje bokstav
        {
            returnedWord += "_ ";
        }
        return returnedWord; //Returnerar värde
    }
    foreach (char letter in word)
    {
        bool letterMatch = false;//Skapar bool-variabel letterMatch som används för att kontrollera om 
        foreach (char character in guessedCharacters)//spelaren skrivit in en korrekt bokstav.
        {
            if (character == letter) //Om karaktären spelaren valt överrenstämmer med en bokstav
            {           //i det nuvarande ordet så visas endast den bokstaven istället för "_".
                returnedWord += character + " ";
                letterMatch = true;//Bool-variabeln sätts till "true" om spelar gör rätt val
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                letterMatch = false; //Om spelaren gör fel val så sätts/fortsätter 
                                     //bool-variabeln letterMatch att vara "falsk"

            }                        
        }
        if (letterMatch == false) //Om letterMatch är "false" så visas ej någon bokstav,
        {                         //utan endast karaktären "_"
            returnedWord += "_ ";
        }
    }
    return returnedWord;
}

    //_____________________________METOD-Gissa bokstav____________________________________________________________________________

    static void letterGuess(List<char> guessedCharacters, string word, string wordToDisplay, ref int numGuessesLeft)
    {
    string letters = "";
    foreach (char letter in guessedCharacters)
    {
        letters += " " + letter;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Gissa på en bokstav mellan A-Ö");
    Console.WriteLine("Gissade bokstäver: " + letters);
    Console.WriteLine("Gissningar kvar: " + numGuessesLeft);
    Console.WriteLine(wordToDisplay);
    string guess = Console.ReadLine();
    char guessedLetter = 'a';
    try
    {
        guessedLetter = Convert.ToChar(guess);
        if (!char.IsLetter(guessedLetter))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {//Hanterar ett udantag om spelaren skriver in mer än 1 karaktär eller om karaktären ej är en bokstav
      Console.WriteLine("Error[3]: Endast en bokstav åt gången");

    }
    bool repeat = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < guessedCharacters.Count; i++)
    {
        if (guessedCharacters[i] == guessedLetter)
        {//Hanterar ett undantag om spelaren skriver in en bokstav som redan är vald
            Console.WriteLine("Error[4]: Du har redan valt den bokstaven, välj en annan");
            repeat = true;

        }
    }
    if (repeat == false)//Om spelare skriver in en bokstav korrekt, utan undantag, så läggs
    { //bokstaven till i gussedLetter för att sedan kunna visas som "gissade bokstäver"
        guessedCharacters.Add(guessedLetter);
        numGuessesLeft -= 1; //En gissning förloras
    }
}

    //_______________________METOD-Kolla om spelare vill spela igen______________________________________

    static void userReplay()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Vill du spela igen? (j/n)");//Ger spelare ett val om omspel.
    string playAgain = Console.ReadLine();//Läser in spelares input.
    if (playAgain == "n")//Om spelare valt "n" avslutas programmet.
    {
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    Console.Clear();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Strixx, make it easier for us to help you. Most of us don't speak swedish, so we cannot use your comments to get to the point faster and your code is darn long for someone to answer you on the spot. You probably know in which method the logic belongs, or at least hint us where you would put it. Maybe extract this method in a different code block? The easier it is for us to help, the faster you will get answers!

Comment: This does I fear come under the category of tl;dr for most people, following @TimBourguignon's excellent advice will improve your question.

Comment: Hello @TimBourguignon , you are absolutetly right, didnt now what i was thinking sending all that and expecting people to understand. Been awake 2 days straight coding, so i am a bit fuzzy in the brain, thanks for your input! @Exxoff´s solution worked perfect for me tough so wont be changing it now as it is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count how many characters there are in `guess` and check if it is the same as `word`.

You may also want to change the error message to display that only letters are allowed since we already handled the "too-many-characters" problem.

```
if(guess.Length > 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(guess == word ? string.Format("Congrats! The correct word was {0}", word) : string.Format("Oh darn! The correct word was '{0}'", word));
    userReplay();

}
else
{
    //Execute your current try block here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string guess = Console.ReadLine();
```

After reading the user input check its size:

```
 if(guess.Length == 1)
 {
    //execute your current logic
 } else if(guess.Length >= 1){
     if(guess == word){
         // right guess
     }else{
      //wrong guess
     }
 }
```

Comment: Think there's a typo here, if length == 1 else if length ==1?